# Android app debug apk does not ask for permissions on some devices

Tags: android, user-permissions

On some devices, the app correctly asks permissions while sidloading. On others (Android 6.0), it does not ask permissions while sideloading at all. The permissions are listed in the manifest.xml (below) and work perfectly for some devices (Android 5.0). On other devices (Android 4.0, 6.0.1), it asks permissions as it should but does not seem to incorporate all of them. The popup below is an example of what happens when a button to send an sms is clicked.

I have only had limited testing and the problems seems to be a little different depending on which android version the device is running. That being said, it could be stemming from something different, I wouldn't know.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.catalizeapp.catalize_ss25">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Catalize"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="Catalize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value="Contacts" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Contacts" />

    <activity android:name=".Account"
        android:theme="@style/SuperCoolAppBarActivity"/>
        <meta-data android:name = "android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value= ".Contacts"/>

    <activity android:name=".ReportBug">
        <meta-data android:name = "android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Contacts"/>
    </activity>
</application></manifest>
```

[(IMAGE) When a button that should send a text message is clicked, this pops up instead of executing the action of the button](http://i.stack.i)

Comment: can you show us activity where you are requesting permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation:

If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the permissions in the manifest, and it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running. The user can grant or deny each permission, and the app can continue to run with limited capabilities even if the user denies a permission request.
That's the reason why althought you have declared the permissions in your manifest file you still need to ask for them at runtime.

As a workaround you can set a minSdkVersion < 23, but also as the documentation says:

Note: Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), users can revoke permissions from any app at any time, even if the app targets a lower API level. You should test your app to verify that it behaves properly when it's missing a needed permission, regardless of what API level your app targets.
Also, according to the Permissions Best Practices you should test against both permission models to provide a better user experience.